# Update Pattern D3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to understand the update pattern in D3.  I have a DOM that I would like to "update" based on a time/date slider.  I am having trouble understanding how to remove my text and replace it with the "new" text.  The way the code is working right now is that it places my text in a long line instead of displaying each new text value when I change my slider.  Please see my inline comments in the code to see where I think I'm having trouble.

```
function drawMonthN(m, nuc, tween){    
   //console.log("m is updating: " + m) 
   //my function is working, it's updating my month

   //console.log("what is nuc: " + JSON.stringify(nuc));
   //as an example it loads my array ([{"time":"Jun-13","yearTotal":33, "Jun-13":4000},{"time":"Jul-13", "yearTotal":44,....)

var svg = d3.select('#num')
        .append("g2")
        .attr('width', 150)
        .attr('height', 20)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");

update(nuc);

function update(data){
    var text = svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(data, function(d, i){
                 //console.log("what is d:  " + JSON.stringify(d.yearTotal));
              return d.yearTotal; });
                //d.yearTotal returns all the totals and display it as a long line of text in the DOM.
          .enter().append("text")
          .attr("class", "enter")
          .attr("dy", ".75em")
          .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
          .text(function(d) { 
           return d.yearTotal; })  
        .transition()
          .duration(750)
          .attr("y", 0)
          .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // EXIT
  // Remove old elements as needed.
  g2.exit().remove();
}

} // end of drawMonth function
```

Based on my mock data I'm using this is what is displayed in #num:
'334353'
I would like '33' to be display, then we I change my dashboard to the next month I would like '43' to be displayed, etc.

```
nuc = 
     [
      {
        "year": "2013",
        "time":"Jun-13",
        "yearTotal": "33",
        "LAT":11.7885,
        "LON":-144.942,
        "Jun-13":4000
      },
      {
        "year": "2013",
        "time":"Jul-13",
        "yearTotal": "43",
        "LAT":52.4378,
        "LON":-50.1609,
        "Jul-13":5000
      },
      {
        "year": "2013",
        "time":"Aug-13",
        "yearTotal": "53",
        "LAT":60.8248,
        "LON":-87.8296,
        "Aug-13":10000
      }
    ]
```

Comment: What is `nuc`? Do you want to update multiple `text` elements or a single one?

Comment: Hi Lars,  above is a sample of the data that represents nuc.  I would like to only update one element:

Comment: So should the displayed number be the sum of the totals?

Comment: I want the "yearTotal" from 'nuc' to display.  So for example, when the 'slider' is on Jun-13 I want '33' to be displayed, when the user changes the 'slider' to Jul-13, I want '43' to be displayed, and finally, when the slider changes to Aug-13, I want '53' to be displayed.  The way I have the code now, this is what is being displayed '334353'  I've played around with the code many different ways, but I feel like this is very close to what I want so hopefully someone can see where my mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3` selections and data-binding are about working with arrays of data and displaying something for each datum in your array.  You bind an array and when data enters, exits or updates in that array you act upon it. In your case, though, you just want to display a single text element with just one piece of data.  You want just one datum in the array.  I would just create a single text element and then you [.datum](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#datum) to switch the data out:

```
// create a single text element
svg.append('text')
  .attr("class", "enter")
  .attr("dy", ".75em")
  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

// update function
function update() {

  // get value from slider
  var val = +d3.select('#myRange').node().value;

  // select our one text element
  d3.select('.enter')
    .datum(nuc[val]) // use datum to assign our one piece of data
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.yearTotal;
    }) // update text
    .style("fill-opacity", 0) // hide so it fades in
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);
```

Here's some working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
  <input type="range" id="myRange" max="2" min="0" step="1">
  
  <script>
    var nuc = [{
      "year": "2013",
      "time": "Jun-13",
      "yearTotal": "33",
      "LAT": 11.7885,
      "LON": -144.942,
      "Jun-13": 4000
    }, {
      "year": "2013",
      "time": "Jul-13",
      "yearTotal": "43",
      "LAT": 52.4378,
      "LON": -50.1609,
      "Jul-13": 5000
    }, {
      "year": "2013",
      "time": "Aug-13",
      "yearTotal": "53",
      "LAT": 60.8248,
      "LON": -87.8296,
      "Aug-13": 10000
    }]

    d3.select('#myRange')
      .on('change',function(){
        update();
      })

    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width',500)
      .attr('height',500);
      
    svg.append('text')
      .attr("class", "enter")
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    function update() {
      
      var val = +d3.select('#myRange').node().value;

      d3.select('.enter')
        .datum(nuc[val])
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.yearTotal;
        })
        .style("fill-opacity", 0)
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);
    }
    
    update();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested you can also do it with the general update pattern as follows:

```js
  var nuc = [{
    "year": "2013",
    "time": "Jun-13",
    "yearTotal": "33",
    "LAT": 11.7885,
    "LON": -144.942,
    "Jun-13": 4000
  }, {
    "year": "2013",
    "time": "Jul-13",
    "yearTotal": "43",
    "LAT": 52.4378,
    "LON": -50.1609,
    "Jul-13": 5000
  }, {
    "year": "2013",
    "time": "Aug-13",
    "yearTotal": "53",
    "LAT": 60.8248,
    "LON": -87.8296,
    "Aug-13": 10000
  }]

  var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width',200)
    .attr('height',100),
    result = Range("body #myRange", "text")(nuc);
  alert("initial value is " + result());

  function Range(input, output){
    var data, update,
        range = d3.select(input)
          .on('change',function(){
        refresh.call(this);
      }),
        val = range.property("value");
    function accessor(d) {
      return d[val].yearTotal;
    }
    function refresh(v) {
      val = v || this.value;
      update = svg.selectAll(output).data([data]);
      var enter = update.enter().append('text')
        .attr("class", "enter")
        .attr("dy", ".75em")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      update.text(accessor)
        .style("fill-opacity", 0)
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);
    }
    return function(_){
      data = _;
      refresh(range.property("value"));
      return accessor.bind(null, data);
    }
  }
```

```css
    #myRange {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="myRange" max="2" min="0" step="1">
```

---

### Key points

The update selection contains only one element because data is wrapped in an array.

```
update = svg.selectAll(output).data([data]);
```

That element however, has the entire data array bound to it so you can do this...

```
  update.text(function (d) {
      return d[val].yearTotal;
  })
```